# ¿Como puedo hacer para que un input solo acepte numeros decimales y no numeros enteros?

Tags: javascript, html

Lo único que he podido hacer en el código es esto:

```
<p><label>Limite de Credito  <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" name="nombre" ></label></p>
```

Comment: vas a manejar el input por javascript?

Comment: Si han contestado tu pregunta márcala como respondida en el tick debajo de valorar

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes solucionar de una manera relativamente sencilla usando una expresión regular

```
/[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}/
```

Vamos a usar un rango de 0 a 9 para los números antes del punto, especificando que debe haber al menos un número antes del punto decimal y al menos un número después del punto decimal

```js
validate.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (toValidate.value.match(/[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}/)) {
    console.log("Válido");
  } else {
    console.log("No válido");
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="toValidate" type="number">
<button id="validate">Validate</button>
```

---

Si prefieres hacerlo solo usando HTML, puedes usar el atributo [`pattern`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <input pattern="[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}">
  <button>Send</button>
</form>
```